GPU Ubuntu settings and configuration
I'm a new Ubuntu user.
I have a few question about the GPU and the system. Below are the system details.
Is it okay that in Graphics it shows my integrated card?
Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Lenovo Legion 5 Pro
Memory:                                      16.0 GiB
Processor:                                   AMD Ryzen™ 7 5800H with Radeon™ Graphics × 16
Graphics:                                    AMD Radeon™ Graphics
Graphics 1:                                  NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3060 Laptop GPU
Disk Capacity:                               (null)

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            GKCN65WW
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-48-generic

I used nvidia-smi command to check the usage of Nvidia and it showed 0%.
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.120                Driver Version: 550.120        CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 ...    Off |   00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   39C    P0            752W /   80W |       9MiB /   6144MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2411      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                              4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

How can I run programs with my Nvidia card?
Also I noticed that my fans work not the same as they did on Windows, now they can stop at the random moment and then continue to work after a few sec. And sometimes during the boot the screen picture starts to shake and looks completely broken. Only reboot helps to fix it. Such problem has never happened on Windows as well.
Obvious solution is to go back to Windows, but  it's not the way :)
One solution that I've found was  to create the  /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/nvidia-prime.conf file and write there.
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia-prime"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "PrimaryGPU" "yes"
EndSection

It really helped but after that my OS started to lags and the temperatures of my cpu  and gpu went to 80-85 just using Google-Chrome then my screen froze and I decided to reinstall the OS completely and now I'm at the start point.

Do not reinvent the wheel by making it square. Undo what you did, reboot, open Nvidia X Server settings and in profile change it to High Performance (Nvidia), reboot and you'll be using the dGPU instead.

@ChanganAuto thank  you for your answer!  I understood that making some config files without understanding isn't the best idea.  Day before I posted the question I had installed the fuse and in the next day i got "nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module Nvidia, inheriting taint."
I fixed it with
sudo apt purge gdm3
sudo apt install gdm3
and then I started to check my nvidia card and it  led to the current question.
